# Vue3 - ref to component child from other library

Tags: vue.js, ref

I have a problem. I want to access to original value in input in gmap autocomplete component. Im new in vue 3 and I can't do it. What wrong is here?

```
<template>
  <div class="location-input">
    <GMapAutocomplete
      class="search"
      placeholder="Szukaj..."
      ref="autocomplete"
      @place_changed="onChange"
    >
    </GMapAutocomplete>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-check" style="color: green;"/>
    <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-xmark" style="color: red;"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>

import {defineEmits, ref} from "vue";
let autocomplete = ref(null);

const onChange = async (value) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(async () => {resolve()}, 1500)
  })
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  console.info(autocomplete.input)
  emit('change', value)
}

const emit = defineEmits(['change'])
</script>
```

GmapAutocomplete component templete:

```
<template>
  <input ref="input" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$attrs" />
</template>
```

Comment: Send the full source code to GMapAutocomplete

Comment: Give `defineExpose` a try in the `GmapAutocomplete`. In Vue 3 nothing is accessible outside of the component, but those are strictly exposed.

Comment: Whenever you define a variable as `ref`, you need to access the current value with `.value`. if you want to access the autocomplete ref, you need to  use `autocomplete.value`.  To solve your problem here: did you try to use `v-model`: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html